# Add a digit to the end of multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the end digit of the target div, replace and join two attributes `(js-data-reveals)` with that digit added at the end (_1).

I know it has something to do with the regular expression that I am using to replace the attributes but I can't figure it out.

Hope you can help.

```js
$('#js-form-group-UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1').find('input').each(function() {
  var attrName = 'js-data-reveals';
  var $el = $(this);
  //Get Last Digit from ID
  var idNumber = $el.attr('id').match(/\d+$/);
  var attrs = $el.attr(attrName);
  //Split the two attributes in js-data-reveals
  var data = attrs.split(',').map(function(item) {
    return item.replace(/.{0}$/, function(idNumber) {
      return idNumber
    });
  });
  $el.attr(attrName, data.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-form-group-UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1"
           js-data-driven="true"
           js-data-reveals="DOCUMENT_TYPE,UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `question-block` element in HTML?

Comment: and if you know that the issue is in regexp then post only regexp with expected output...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match "Return value: If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by any results captured in parentheses."

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Change HTML

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @Qbessi  check my answer once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

match() returns an array.

Can simplify this using [`attr(attrName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

```js
$('input[js-data-reveals]').attr('js-data-reveals', function(_, existing) {
  var idNumber = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
  return existing.split(',').map(function(s) {
    // replace number if it already exists or add it if it doesn't
    return s.match(/_\d+$/) 
           ? s.replace(/\d+$/, idNumber)
           : s += '_' + idNumber;
  }).join();
});


console.log($('#UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1').attr('js-data-reveals'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-form-group-UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_ID_1" 
       js-data-driven="true" 
       js-data-reveals="DOCUMENT_TYPE,UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION_999">
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked better than I expected. Just need to figure out how to replace the digit if one already exists in the attributes. Thank you.

Comment: Use same `match` to see if one already exists. Not sure what you need if it does

Comment: Well I just want to replace the digit if it does exist with the one captured from the ID

Comment: so it might be like `js-data-reveals="DOCUMENT_TYPE_57,UPLOAD_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION_83"`?? And you want `57` and `83` to be `1` from id?

Comment: Exactly; so really just remove any existing digits - maybe add a replace() after split?

Comment: See update...one of them has existing number, the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '+' in your Regular Expression to make it:

```
var idNumber = $el.attr('id').match(/\d$/);
```

The '+' makes a Regular Expression match the given character 1 or more times, so \d+$ would match 12345 in 'd12345'. Since you only want the last digit to match, removing the '+' will make it works as expected.